# Rspec with headless Chrome/Chromium on Alpine Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, alpine-linux

On Alpine 3.10.1, I'm trying to run RSpec with `headless_chrome`.

```
 config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome
  end
```

I have installed `capybara` and `webdrivers`.

Since I haven't found a way to install `Chrome` on Alpine, I have tried with `Chromium` (76.0.3809.87-r0). But, when I run the spec, it doesn't find the driver.

> ChildProcess::LaunchError: No such file or directory -
>   /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver

I have tried also to install `chromium-chromedriver` directly via apk but the outcome has been the same.

Is there a way to install `Chrome` on Alpine or to use `Chromium` with `Capybara`?

Comment: I'm facing this too — tests previously running successfully with Chromium installed under `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`. Switching to `webdrivers`/`selenium-webdriver` gives the error you're seeing. Even with `WD_CHROME_PATH` set. The file `chromedriver` is actually there any the Jenkins user has permiissions for it too.

Comment: We had this kind of errors in the past. Not sure it can help you but here is an extract of part of our patch for Linux platforms: "Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = (`which chromium`.presence || `which chromium-browser`).chomp"

Answer (score 5):

There are three things necessary to get this working:

1. Use selenium-webdriver instead of webdrivers
2. Install chromium, chromium-chromedriver and selenium on your Docker image
3. Configure a Capybara driver

Details below.

#### Use selenium-webdriver instead of webdrivers

If you happen to be using the webdrivers gem in your `Gemfile`, replace it with `selenium-webdriver`.

#### Install chromium, chromium-chromedriver and selenium on your Docker image

Alter your `Dockerfile` so that the following packages are being installed:

```
chromium chromium-chromedriver python3 python3-dev py3-pip
```

Then, after that, include the line `RUN pip3 install -U selenium`.

Below is a full sample `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine AS builder

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base libffi-dev \
    nodejs yarn tzdata \
    postgresql-dev postgresql-client zlib-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev readline-dev bash \
    #
    # For testing
    chromium chromium-chromedriver python3 python3-dev py3-pip \
    #
    # Nice-to-haves
    git vim \
    #
    # Fixes watch file issues with things like HMR
    libnotify-dev

RUN pip3 install -U selenium

FROM builder AS development

# Add the current apps files into docker image
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install any extra dependencies via Aptfile - These are installed on Heroku
# COPY Aptfile /usr/src/app/Aptfile
# RUN apk add --update $(cat /usr/src/app/Aptfile | xargs)

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/bin:$PATH

# Install latest bundler
RUN bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]

FROM development AS production

COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app
COPY .ruby-version /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app

# Install Ruby Gems
RUN bundle config set deployment 'true'
RUN bundle config set without 'development:test'
RUN bundle check || bundle install --jobs=$(nproc)

# Install Yarn Libraries
RUN yarn install --check-files

# Copy the rest of the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Precompile the assets
RUN RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret-key-base RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Precompile Bootsnap
run RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret-key-base RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile app/ lib/
```

#### Configure a Capybara driver

Put the following in `spec/support/chrome.rb`.

```
# spec/support/chrome.rb

driver = :selenium_chrome_headless

Capybara.server = :puma, {Silent: true}

Capybara.register_driver driver do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1400")

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = driver

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by driver
  end
end
```

I wrote up a little more detail in a [blog post I wrote on this topic](https://www.codewithjason.com/run-rspec-headless-chrome-chromium-alpine-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer (and blog post)!  I was wondering if you could discuss why selenium-webdriver vs webdrivers (as webdrivers was the pointed to from the deprecated chromedriver-helper)?  Any substantial differences?  I'm haven't done front-end testing in a long time, so just trying to get a better feel for the current situation as I try to jump back in.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could remember but I can't. My fuzzy memory is that webdrivers gave some kind of error or failed in some way like that.

Answer (score 3):

Jason Swett's answer ultimately works but it has a lot of overhead. Most notably to get Capybara working on Alpine I didn't need to install Selenium or Python.

The simplest way I found to get RSpec + Capybara working on Alpine:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:3.0.2-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache chromium chromium-chromedriver
```

`Gemfile`

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara' # 3.36.0 as of writing this
  gem 'selenium-webdriver' # 4.0.3 as of writing this
  # Make sure no other gems are installed, such as `webdrivers`
end
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chromium do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,900")
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, capabilities: options)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chromium
```